# Verificar diferença entre resultados não listado e identificar qual dia da semana é a data

Tags: sql, query

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT 
    V.CHAPA,
    F.NOME,
    V.DATA,
    MAX(V.SEQUENCIALBATIDA) AS BATIDA
      FROM
            ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW AS V
            LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC  AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
        WHERE
            V.CHAPA = 9132
        AND BATIDA IS NOT NULL 
        AND V.CODCOLIGADA = 1 
        AND  YEAR ( V.DATA ) = 2016 
        AND MONTH ( V.DATA ) = 9
         GROUP BY V.CHAPA,
                  F.NOME,
                  V.DATA 
          ORDER BY V.DATA ASC
```

Ela me retorna:

```
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-02 00:00:00.000 4
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-03 00:00:00.000 4
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-04 00:00:00.000 2
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-05 00:00:00.000 4
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-06 00:00:00.000 4

>>> 1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-07 00:00:00.000 2
>>> 1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-09 00:00:00.000 4

1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-10 00:00:00.000 4
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-11 00:00:00.000 2
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-12 00:00:00.000 4
1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-13 00:00:00.000 4

>>> 1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-14 00:00:00.000 4
>>> 1234    JOAO DA SILVA   2016-09-16 00:00:00.000 4
```

Como podem ver nos locais onde marquei com `>>>`  não existe registro naquela data, exemplo: `da data 7 pula para  a data 9` e `da data 14 pula para a 16` ,isso ta correto porque nesse dia não teve movimentação.

O que preciso saber:
 Quantos dia ente o `dia 08 e o dia 15` que são os dias que não tem movimentação pois esse período não pode ultrapassar 7 dias.

Outro paramento que preciso é:
 Nessa mesma consulta:

```
SELECT 
    V.CHAPA,
    F.NOME,
    V.DATA,
    MAX(V.SEQUENCIALBATIDA) AS BATIDA
      FROM
            ARELBATIDATRANSITOVIEW AS V
            LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC  AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
        WHERE
            V.CHAPA = 9132
        AND BATIDA IS NOT NULL 
        AND V.CODCOLIGADA = 1 
        AND  YEAR ( V.DATA ) = 2016 
        AND MONTH ( V.DATA ) = 9
         GROUP BY V.CHAPA,
                  F.NOME,
                  V.DATA 
          ORDER BY V.DATA ASC
```

Eu preciso identificar qual dia da semana é a data, e listar somente os domingos.

Como poderia proceder com esses dois casos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--Dias entre dia 8 e dia 15

Pra que você quer saber saber isso se você pode ver os dias da semana com DATENAME (por extenso) e DATEPART? Favor formular melhor a questão...

--DOMINGO

WHERE DATEPART(dw,V.DATA) = 1

Comment: Quanto ao domingo,perfeito,Obrigado. Quanto ao saber  Dias entre dia 8 e dia 15 e porque esse dias seriam os dias de folga dos funcionários, o que preciso saber a diferença de dias entre um funcionário e outro  pois a diferença não pode ultrapassar 7 dias se ultrapassar eu preciso exibir no resultado